# Every vector with sum of elemtents equal to zero is eigenvector of symmetric matrix whose rows and columns sum is equal?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Suppose there is a symmetric matrix such that the sum of elements in every row equals the sum of elements in every column. One example of such a matrix is:

\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & b \\
b & a & b \\
b & b & a
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I have noticed that every vector whose elements sum up to zero is an eigenvector of a matrix satisfying the above criteria. How to prove this and what would be the way to tell what the eigenvalue corresponding to such an eigenvector is?

Thank you!

Comment: The way I'm reading this, it seems to me that you are saying that for all (non-zero) vectors there is a matrix such as above such that the vector is an eigenvalue of the matrix. And, well, every non-zero vector is an eigenvector of the $0$ matrix and/or of the identity matrix.

Comment: Or is it the other way around? That for all symmetric matrices with constant sum of rows and for all non-zero vectors of zero sum, the vector is an eigenvector of the matrix?

Comment: "That for all symmetric matrices with constant sum of rows and for all non-zero vectors of zero sum, the vector is an eigenvector of the matrix?" - This is correct with the addition that the sum of columns is constant as well and equal to the sum of rows. For example the sum of elements in row 1 = 2*b + a, and the sum of elements in col 1 = 2*b + a. The same applies to any random row and column.

Comment: The sum of colums being equal to the sum of rows follows from symmetry.

Comment: That is not true??? A = diag(1,2) is symmetric but the sum of elements along col1=1, whereas it is equal to 2 for col2.

Comment: ... which is perfectly in accordance with the fact the sum of rows of $\operatorname{diag}(1,2)$ is not constant either.

Comment: In the above example A1 = { {a,b,b},{b,a,b},{b,b,a}}, the sum of elements along every individual row is 2b+a and the same applies to the sum of elements along every column. Lets say that A2 = { {a,0,b},{0,a,b},{b,b,a}} now. What one can notice is that the sum of elements in col1 = a+b, whereas the sum of elements in col3 = 2b+a. Even though A2 is symmetric it does not satisfy the criteria I listed in the original question...

Comment: Again: the rows of $\begin{pmatrix}a&0&b\\ 0&a&b\\ b&b&a\end{pmatrix}$ do not sum to the same value, just like its columns do not. Unless, of course, when $b=0$, in which case all the columns sum to the same value as all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false. Maybe these examples are clearer than Gae. S's.
Let $$A=\pmatrix{0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0},\quad
B=\pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1},
\quad\text{ and }\quad
v=\pmatrix{1\\-1\\0\\0}.$$
It is easy to check that the matrices $A$ and $B$ are symmetric with all row and column sums equal and that the elements of vector $v$ sum up to zero.  But, contrary to what the OP asserts, $v$ is not an eigenvector of $A$ or of $B$.

In general, if $A$ is symmetric and has all row sums equal to $s$, then the
vector of all $1$s is an eigenvector of $A$, with eigenvalue $s$.  If $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to a different eigenvalue, then the sum of the entries in $v$ vanishes.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a general way to identify the eigenvalues(vectors) of such a matrix?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{gae}[1]{\newcommand{#1}{\operatorname{#1}}}\gae{rk}$The claim is false for $n\ge 3$. For $n=3$, the space $V$ of symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices with constant sum of rows has dimension $1+\frac{3(3-1)}2=4$ and specifically the map $$\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\ a\\ b\\ c\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}a&b&\lambda-(a+b)\\ b&c&\lambda-(b+c)\\ \lambda-(a+b)&\lambda-(b+c)&a+2b-\lambda+c\end{pmatrix}$$

is an isomorphism $\Phi:\Bbb R^4\to V$. Your claim is that for all $a$, $b$, $c$, $\lambda$, $x$ and $y$ it should hold that the two vectors $$\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ -x-y\end{pmatrix},\quad \begin{pmatrix}a&b&\lambda-(a+b)\\ b&c&\lambda-(b+c)\\ \lambda-(a+b)&\lambda-(b+c)&a+2b-\lambda+c\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ -x-y\end{pmatrix}$$

are linearly dependent. Since two column vectors $v,w$ are linearly dependent if and only if $\rk\begin{pmatrix}v^T\\ w^T\end{pmatrix}<2$, we have that the assertion is equivalent to $$\rk\begin{pmatrix}x&y&-x-y\\ ax+by+(\lambda-a-b)(x+y)&bx+cy+(\lambda-b-c)(x+y)&\text{stuff...}\end{pmatrix}<2$$

For all $x$, $y$, $a$, $b$, $c$ and $\lambda$. However, the determinant of the submatrix made of the first two columns is already not the zero polynomial: it should be $$-2 a x y - a y^2 + 2 b x^2 - 2 b y^2 + c x^2 + 2 c x y - \lambda x^2 + \lambda y^2$$

which means that the rank of that matrix is $2$ for some $(x,y,a,b,c,\lambda)$.

For $n\ge4$ we can include a counterexample for $n=3$ in a block-diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\ 0&\lambda I\end{pmatrix}$, and then test it against the vector $(x,y,-x-y,0,\cdots,0)^T$.

Comment: You can also think another way.
In the observed case, A is obviosly a full rank matrix. By looking into its structure, one can conclude that one eigenvector of A is V1 = [1,1, ..., 1]. As A is also symmetric matrix, we know that all the other eigenvectors must be orthogonal to V1. In other words, every other eigenvector must have the sum of element being equal to zero. However, what is the way to find the expression for eigenvalues in this case?

Comment: @slm992 I've aready asked you what you wanted to know *exactly*, you've already given me *an* answer and I've already addressed the question in the form you've said in that occasion. I will not go through any of those passages again.